# How to create a class decorating another class using python

Tags: python, decorator, magic-methods, isinstance

My goal is to implement a [classic Decorator pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator) (not functional @decorator, provided by python from the box). But I don't want to implement every method and attribute in decorator class. I want to make it in a more universal and elegant way.

My approach:

```py
class AbstractDecorator:
    base_class: type = None

    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        # If there is no attribute or method in current object, lookup in base instance
        return getattr(self.instance, item)

   
class Original:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_val = 1


class ConcreteDecorator(AbstractDecorator):
    base_class = Original


original = Original()
decorated = ConcreteDecorator(original)

print(decorated.some_val)
# prints 1, everything is OK
```

And everything here is working fine, instead of one thing:

```py
print(isinstance(decorated, Original))
# Prints False
```

The first thing I thought I could use were magic methods. I've found [**isinstancecheck** and **issubclasscheck** methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks). But they only act, when an instance is checked to be class that uses them, e. g. `isinstance(something, AbstractDecorator)`. But I need to modify the opposite: `isinstance(decorated, some_other_class)`.

Is there a way to do it? I haven't found one...

Comment: Your objects are in fact not instances of `Original`. Trying to lie about that will probably do more harm than good.

Comment: If you want your code to treat `decorated` the same way it would treat instances of `Original`, you probably *shouldn't write* `isinstance(decorated, Original)`. You should write code that expresses what you actually mean.

Comment: Yes. My objects are not instances of `Original`. Though they fully support `Original` interface, all its methods and attributes and can be used as `Original`. It doesn't matter, how `Original` will be changed in the future, it will still be supported without changing decorators. That is what decorators are designed for: to incapsulate transparrently inner instance behavior and extend it.

Comment: If you look at code examples (https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator/python/example), pattern acts absolutely the same, but redeclares all methods of original class. In my case, base classes may contain different methods and attributes (though they all inherit same django.db.Model class). I don't want full redeclaring as it makes me modify decorators on each change of base classes and implement things I don't need for each concrete decorator. I want to create many decorated classes and add them common functionality. The example above is simplified to show a concrete problem.